# feh image viewer: toggle frameless/move window

Tags: feh

With the feh image viewer I can open a frameless window on an image. This is good.

However now I want to move the window on the screen and to do that I guess I will need a frame.

So is there a way of moving a window or of toggling the `frameless` feature.

I don't see the option in `~/.config/feh/keys` or in `man feh`.

Comment: Pure speculation, try with `F11` key :)

Comment: Or `Alt+space`, `m`, `(arrow keys)`

Comment: @RomeoNinov Tada! The alt-space brings up the window menu..  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this sequence of keys:

```
ALT+space
```

then

```
m
```

then use arraw keys to move the windows

Answer (score 0):

In `feh` you can press **<kbd>F</kbd>** (the F key) to toggle between fullscreen and window mode.